# mysql get count of columns having a value above and below a certain value in a row

Tags: mysql

As I get a row, I also want to grab the number of rows that are below a value in the selected row and a separate count of rows that are above a value of the selected row.

What's the best method of doing this?

The following obviously is wrong, but might illustrate what I mean...

```
SELECT page.*,COUNT(less_than_threshold.id) as `smaller`,    
COUNT(greater_than_threshold.id) as `bigger`

FROM `learning_pages` as pages

JOIN learning_pages as less_than_threshhold on page.class_id=less_than_threshold.class_id 
AND less_than_threshhold.content_count < page.content_count

JOIN learning_pages as greater_than_threshold ON 
page.class_id=greater_than_threshold.class_id AND 
greater_than_threshold.content_count>page.content_count

WHERE page.id=5
```

*EDIT*
As requested:

```
learning_pages
id (BIG INT) | content_count (INT) | type (VARCHAR) | author_id (BIG INT) | date_updated (DATETIME)| class_id(BIG_INT)
```

Truncated values

(id,content_count)
   VALUES(1,3), (2,4), (3,3), (4,5), (5,3), (6,2),(7,1), (8,3), (9,2)
  ...

With

```
SELECT page.*,COUNT(less_than_threshold.id) as `smaller`
FROM `learning_pages` as pages

JOIN learning_pages as less_than_threshhold on page.class_id=less_than_threshold.class_id 
AND less_than_threshhold.content_count < page.content_count

WHERE page.id=5
```

I get a `smaller` count of 3, which is correct. Adding the `bigger` count to that is the issue. The solution I have is a sub_query which I fear is not the best solution here...

```
 SELECT page.*, count(i.id) as `bigger` FROM 
(SELECT lp.*,COUNT(clp.id) as `smaller` FROM `learning_pages` as lp 
JOIN learning_pages as clp on lp.class_id=clp.class_id AND 
clp.content_count<lp.content_count WHERE lp.id=5) as page 

JOIN learning_pages as i ON page.class_id =i.class_id WHERE page.id=5
```

Comment: give an example data and example result.

Answer (score 1):

You can `DISTINCT` the result. Use the following query:

```
SELECT page.*,
COUNT( DISTINCT less_than_threshold.id) as `smaller`,    
COUNT( DISTINCT greater_than_threshold.id) as `bigger`

FROM `learning_pages` as page

JOIN learning_pages as less_than_threshold 
on page.class_id=less_than_threshold.class_id 
AND less_than_threshold.content_count < page.content_count

JOIN learning_pages as greater_than_threshold 
ON page.class_id=greater_than_threshold.class_id 
AND greater_than_threshold.content_count>page.content_count

WHERE page.id=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using queries in select statement:

```
SELECT pages.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM pages
        WHERE pages.id < 5
    ) AS less_than_threshold,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM pages
        WHERE pages.id > 5
    ) AS greater_than_threshold
FROM pages
WHERE pages.id = 5;
```